# Running Total for Grouped Counts

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hoping someone can help... I have a mental blank....  I am sure this is easy...

I need to add a Running Total column to my View.

My table has two main fields I want to utilise

AccNo and Start Date.  I want to count the Accno's grouped by Year & Month.

So far I am using

```
select      {fn Monthname(startdate) } as MonthName,
            YEAR(startdate) as Year,
            count(accno) as [Count]
from        DR_ACCS
where       startdate > '01/01/2016'
group by    { fn MONTHNAME(STARTDATE) }, Month(STARTDATE), year(startdate)
order by    year(startdate),month(startdate)
```

This is giving me

```
MonthName Year  Count
January   2016  24
February  2016  33
March     2016  47
April     2016  25
May       2016  34
June      2016  29
July      2016  46
August    2016  51
```

But I now want to add a "Running total" Column.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
;With CTE as (
select      {fn Monthname(startdate) } as MonthName,
            YEAR(startdate) as Year,
            count(accno) as [Count]
from        DR_ACCS
where       startdate > '01/01/2016'
group by    { fn MONTHNAME(STARTDATE) }, Month(STARTDATE), year(startdate)
order by    year(startdate),month(startdate)
)
select monthname,year,count,sum(count) over(order by count)Running total from cte
group by monthname,year,count,
```

Comment: Thanks... I did try something like this, but it seems I cannot use the order by in the CTE function.  I get this error.   Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.